# Is there a standard practice for synchronizing SQL Server tables?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I've written an application that retrieves pricing and part options from a SQL database to generate a 3D Model of the product and create a sales proposal.  My client likes it so much they want to be able to use it on laptops in the field now.  The catch is, they won't have an internet connection.

I'm considering setting up a SQLite database as part of the standard installation.  The SQLite database on each laptop will synchronize with the main database when the internet connection is re-established.

Are there best practices regarding synchronizing SQL tables like this?  Are there any pitfalls I should consider?  I'm open to all options.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this going to be a one-way or a two-way synchronization?

Comment: Two-way.  I'll be pushing back the sale quotes in case someone else takes over the quoting.

Comment: Yes but the sales quotes aren't necessarily the same data as the pricing and/or part options.  You might have two one-way syncs, part options and pricing down, and sales quotes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Introduction to Sync Framework Database Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx)

Look at the sample [Getting Started: Client and Server Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726015%28SQL.105%29.aspx) which provides a simple example of offline synchronization between a central SQL Server database and SQL Server Compact Edition on the client(s). You'd probably end up using SQL Server CE for this instead of SQLite, but they are comparable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how complex your application is, or how many laptops it will be installed on, but it sounds like in addition to replication of the data you may want to look at your application deployment strategy too.

Have you looked into doing a [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) deployment for this application? Its a nice complement to the Sync Framework and will let you "Sync" your application updates along with data.